# Clear variables values in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am reading two text files to set the values of two variables (u,l). Now I want to write script to run multiple files. When it is reading first file it will set the variables from the respective files but when it is reading second file it will set the same values of those variables.

```
@echo on
set /p u=< ul.txt
set /p l=< ll.txt
echo %u%-%l%
```

I tried SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL option but in that case it is not reading variables values and getting error that ECHO is off. Even I wrote `set u=`   and `set l=`   at the initial of the script but not working in my case.

Comment: `echo is off` means, your variable is empty. Are you sure, the batchfile runs in the same directory where the txt files are? (add `dir ul.txt` to your script to check whether the file is found.)

Comment: Yes sir batch file runs in the same directory where the txt files are. My script is finding the files but it unable to set the variable values for the second file.

Comment: works fine for me. There has to be something else... Does the code _as you wrote it in your question_ really not work for you?

Comment: The code is a part of my script, which is working proper when it is reading first file but for the second file my ul.txt and ll.txt are changing as per the code but the values of variables are not changing respectively. The variables set with the previous file values.

Comment: That cannot be all your code if it is not working.  You need to show ALL of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as given, works fine. However, I'm guessing it is code from inside an if statement, or for loop. If that is the case, you should use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). You can use delayded expansion like this:

> This is an example, not the exact code you need:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if 1 equ 1 (
set /p "u=< ul.txt"
set /p "l=< ll.txt"
echo !u!-!l!
)
pause

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,1) DO (
set /p "u=< ul.txt"
set /p "l=< ll.txt"
echo !u!-!l!
)
pause

set /p u=< ul.txt
set /p l=< ll.txt
echo %u%-%l%
pause
```

Note that inside the if statement and for loop, you replace `%` signs, when they are around variable names, with `!`. So `%someVar%` becomes `!someVar!`, but `%%F` stays `%%F`.

Outside of if statements and for loops, so outside of `()`, you use the normal `%someVar%`

Comment: Dear Dennis van Gils                                                                                                                                                                                                       Thank you for your an answer  but in my case it is not a part of a if statement but it's part of for loop, which I am using to run the multiple file.

Comment: Then the answer remains the same you should use ! Instead of %